# Сортировка словаря по значению (убывание)

Tags: python, сортировка, словари

Есть словарь, ключ(город) и значение (формула подсчёта %-ов).
Необходимо выводить пары `ключ-значение`, *отсортированные по убыванию значения*.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

```
ARIZONA = 1200
ARIZONA_LIMIT = 1899

BOSTON = 561
BOSTON_LIMIT = 3622

CALIFORNIA = 5800
CALIFORNIA_LIMIT = 8900

DENVER = 15000
DENVER_LIMIT = 80000



#СЛОВАРЬ
EVERY_ONE = {'ARIZONA' : ((ARIZONA * 100) / ARIZONA_LIMIT), 
             'BOSTON' : ((BOSTON * 100) / BOSTON_LIMIT), 
             'CALIFORNIA' : ((CALIFORNIA * 100) / CALIFORNIA_LIMIT), 
             'DENVER' : ((DENVER * 100) / DENVER_LIMIT)}

print(EVERY_ONE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете сгенерировать новый словарь на основе списка, полученного функцией `sorted`, которой в качестве ключа сортировки была передана функция получения значения по ключу из словаря (`get`).

***Пример (python3.7+):***

```py
d = {'ARIZONA': 63.191153238546605, 'BOSTON': 15.48868028713418, 'CALIFORNIA': 65.1685393258427, 'DENVER': 18.75}

d = {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)}
print(d)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'CALIFORNIA': 65.1685393258427, 'ARIZONA': 63.191153238546605, 'DENVER': 18.75, 'BOSTON': 15.48868028713418}
```

Comment: Наверное, можно добавить, что до 3.7 версии python в словаре не гаранитровалось, что порядок элементов совпадает с порядком их вставки, т.е. сортировать надо было бы при выводе словаря, а не при его создании

Comment: Спасибо)))))))))